# logic in sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
connect1($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name1);

$q="SELECT DISTINCT
bizinfo.dbiz_id,
bizinfo.company_name,
bizinfo.company_industry,
bizinfo.company_sub_industry
FROM
bizinfo
Inner Join biz_feedback ON bizinfo.dbiz_id = biz_feedback.biz_id AND biz_feedback.on_industry = bizinfo.company_industry
ORDER BY
bizinfo.dbiz_id ASC";
$rs_q=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_q))
{
$dbiz_id=$row['dbiz_id'];
$company=$row['company_name'];
$company_industry=$row['company_industry'];
$company_sub_industry=$row['company_sub_industry'];

connect2($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name2);

$sql_livedb=mysql_query("UPDATE bizinfo set bizinfo.company_industry='$company_industry', bizinfo.company_sub_industry='$company_sub_industry'
WHERE bizinfo.dbiz_id='$dbiz_id'");
}
```

When this code is run, all rows in the `company_industry` and `company_sub_industry` columns are filled with the same data (for the first `biz_id`).

Somewhere a join needs to happen, but I thought I had it covered here `WHERE bizinfo.dbiz_id='$dbiz_id'`.

Comment: It's time to move on from PHP's deprecated mysql_ API. See PDO and/or mysqli_, AND prepared statements.

Comment: Its going to be hard to understand/fix without knowing the structure and/or whats in the tables. Maybe if you could post the affected rows/columns before the operation, the results, and the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't at all obvious what your problem is, but I would guess that there is a value in one of the variables (probably `$company_sub_industry`)  which has a single quote embedded in it, and consequently results in the `WHERE` clause being ignored.

Change your code to remove the update statement and instead dump the values so you can check them. Perhaps some error checking after/in `mysql_query` would help.

If this is the cause, the real solution is to not generate SQL by concatenating strings and variables. Research "php avoid SQL injection" for more info.